# Why the space is not getting detected, even there is space?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i check if SPACE exist? Following name should only print first word.

```
//  var chip_eid = {
//"firstname": "Rubin Rose",
// }; 
if (/^ *$/.test(chip_eid.firstname)) { // Find the SPACE?
  var res = chip_eid.firstname.split(" "); // take Rubin only
  member_firstname = res[0];
}  
else {
  member_firstname = chip_eid.firstname;
}
console.log(member_firstname); // Printing Rubin Rose instead of Rubin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check for spaces. If spaces are there the split will give you the firstname result in the 0th position in the array and when there is none the whole firstname string will be in the 0th position in the array.

```js
var chip_eid = {
"firstname": "RubinRose",
}; 
if(chip_eid.firstname.includes(" "))
  {var res = chip_eid.firstname.split(" "); 
  member_firstname = res[0];
  }
  else
  member_firstname =chip_eid.firstname ;
 
console.log(member_firstname);
```

Comment: Still you could do it without checking. The results will be the same. If simply you put Ashay and split it on space, it will give the whole string as the 1st array element. Results will be the same either way.

Comment: Careful with things like: " Rubin Rose" where it is no longer in the 0th result

Comment: In this case the regex logic or includes will fail too. we had to know the firstname property before hand to search for the name in the array

Comment: Understood, I am just mentioning it since it is likely a case the Asker would need to consider

Answer (score 1):

Try to use '/\s/' instead of '/^ *$/'

```js
var chip_eid = {
  "firstname": "Rubin Rose",
};
if (/\s/.test(chip_eid.firstname)) { // Find the SPACE?
  var res = chip_eid.firstname.split(" "); // take Rubin only
  member_firstname = res[0];
} else {
  member_firstname = chip_eid.firstname;
}
console.log(member_firstname);
```